# Is it possible to restrict the movement of 3D objects within a box in Blender?

Tags: objects, constraints, motion-capture

I have 33 sphere objects positioned according to data from a txt file using Python scripting, forming a humanoid figure.

[image: How the animation looks like.]

However, the figure tends to move out of the camera frame or may have spheres with large z-values. (As seen below)

[image: The problem]

Is it feasible to constrain the figure's movements within a box.

[image: A box]

Limiting the figure's movements within the object

```
def start():
    # Read landmark data from file
    global lines
    with open(filePath, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()

def update(scene):
    global counter
    global lines

    # Split the line into individual coordinates
    points = lines[counter].strip().split(',')

    # Get the collection containing the sphere objects
    collection_name = "Spheres"  # Change this to the name of your collection
    collection = bpy.data.collections.get(collection_name)

    # Check if the collection exists
    if collection:
        # Iterate over objects in the collection
        for obj in collection.objects:
            # Ensure the object is a sphere (you might need to adjust this check based on your scene)
            if obj.type == 'MESH':
                # Extract the index from the object name
                index = int(obj.name.split('Sphere')[-1])

                # Extract coordinates from the data
                x = float(points[index * 3]) / 100
                y = float(points[index * 3 + 1]) / 100
                z = float(points[index * 3 + 2]) / 300

                # Set the position of the sphere object
                obj.location = (x, z, y)
```

These are the functions that handles the animation.
(x, y, z values here are random)

Comment: Don't understand what you want.  Do you want a box that is sized to contain 33 arbitrary spheres?  Or do you want to move 33 spheres from outside to inside a box of some particular size?  You can do either, but you can't do both-- the spheres cannot depend on a box which depends on the spheres.

Comment: i think the problem is here, that you ask for a technical solution, which might be solved easier. Maybe you better tell us about your end goal?

Comment: How is the figure being moved? If it's key-framed, isn't it the animation which requires constraint? It would really help if you could illustrate to show both constraining and constrained elements, to remove any ambiguity.

Comment: @RobinBetts I've updated my question with visual data to provide a clearer understanding of what I'm aiming to achieve. The images illustrate the current state of my project and the desired outcome.

Comment: @Nathan I think the result I'm hoping for is that I want the 33 spheres from outside to be inside of a box. However I want it to mirror the same movements it did outside inside the said box. I hope I'm not being difficult?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer what you're asking, but I doubt it's a good solution to your ultimate problem.

We have a few spheres, and a box.  We want the spheres to fit in the box.  We want the spheres to be in the same orientation to each other after fitting them in the box.  The box is of arbitrary size and orientation.

There's more than one way to try to fit things into that box.  Sometimes, we could rotate them, sometimes, we could move them.  But the only general solution is to resize them.  Here, we can see that the spheres are too big to fit in the box unless we resize them.  And, resizing alone can always fit things into the box.

Notice the box I'm using.  It is a cube that I've transformed only in object mode.  Its faces still point in its object axes.  Its scale is all object scaling, so its object space bounds are still -1,1.

We'll start by selecting our spheres and adding them to a new collection, to simplify instancing.  Then we'll create a geometry nodes modifier for our cube:

[image]

We've got three parallel trunks here, so I'm only showing one.  We instance the collection and then measure the largest positive or negative position in a single object axis; we take the multiplicative inverse of this (ie divide by 1); we pick the smallest of these values of computed from each of the three object axes.  We scale the collection by that to fit it into the cube.

We could scale non-uniformly instead, but that won't preserve the world-space angles between the spheres, which is probably what you want to preserve.  Notice also that while we are fitting things into the box, we are not bothering to *center* things in the box.  That would be possible as well-- but especially since this probably isn't a good solution to your ultimate problem, it makes sense to discover that by building it in its simplest form, rather than a more complex form that still won't be a good solution.